# Text classification with a Language Model (LM) with class labels existing in text tokens

Tags: pytorch, nlp, classification, bert-language-model

I have a multi-label text classification task. The train data labels are categories that might exist as tokens in the training data texts. For instance, some observations look like the following:

```
Train=[["input": "Dogs are animals. Dogs  ove humans.", class: ["dog"]],
       ["input": "Cats are running in the street.", class: ["cat"]],
       ["input": "Cats and dogs live with humans.", class: ["cat", "dog"]],
       ["input": "These animals don't each chocolate.", class: ["dog"]]]
```

I want to train a classifier by fine-tuning a language model using  Pytorch. My question is if I must ensure that the class labels are masked in the training input text? If not, will the classifier overfit or lose generalizability?

If I must mask the labels in the inputs, how can I do it using Pytorch?

Comment: No, I don't recommend masking the tokens. Rather, I would try to see how many samples actually contain trivial answers like the ones you posted. If all of your samples are like this then you have a data issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the label will be mapped to continuous integers, so the model does not know that the text contains the label.
Secondly, you are right, the dog label high probability model will pay more attention to the dog word in the text, but not because the text contains the label, but a feature.
Finally, if you want the model to learn more features that are not related to label words, do not use MASK and replace them with other label words. It is a good solution at present. Refer to [MABEL: Attenuating Gender Bias using Textual Entailment Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.14975)